# Why my code works different after adding a non-relevant line of code?

Tags: c++

I want to get the sum of the three biggest numbers in an array. After sorting them in ascending, I just sum the last three to get my result. Here is when the funny thing happens - my commented code where I tested the sorting before calculating the sum is actually what makes the code correct. When I delete/comment it, the answer becomes different.

Then, i tried just printing n, and it worked fine again, and after commenting it as well, the result changed again incorrectly.

```
int main()
{

    int n;
    cout<<"n: ";
    cin>>n;

    int a[n-1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
/*
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
*/

cout<<endl;

//cout<<n<<endl;

int ourSum = a[n-1] + a[n-2] + a[n-3];

if(n>2)cout<<"The sum of the 3 biggest is "<<ourSum<<endl;
else cout<<"Need at least three numbers"<<endl;
```

with the print cycle OR with the n-print:
n: 6
654321
1 2 3 4 5 6
The sum of the 3 biggest is 15

without the things above which are currently commented:
n: 6
654321
The sum of the 3 biggest is 12

So when the comments are active, the answer is showing correctly: 15. however, when they are commented/removed, the result is 12. I have no idea what's causing this so I'd appreciate an explanation here.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++)` - think about what that top-end limit it on the *initial* pass (i.e. the first pass when `i = 0`). Now think about what `if(a[j]>a[j+1])` means, specifically the latter term of that boolean expression. You're code invokes undefined behavior. Unrelated, you're using non-standard VLAs in C++ code. Opt for a vector instead.

Comment: `int a[n-1]` sets up another buffer overflow

Comment: Firstly, `cin >> n;  int a[n-1];`  is not valid C++ (albeit, unfortunately, some compilers support it as a non-standard extension). Assuming a compiler that supports that feature, the following loop writes to elements `a[0]` to `a[n-1]` but `a[n-1]` does not exist - so the behaviour is undefined. A common symptom of undefined behaviour is that changing unrelated code (e.g "adding a non-relevant line of code") can cause the program to SEEM to work.  The real fix is to avoid undefined behaviour - in this case, only access elements `a[0]` to `a[n-2]` of an array `a` with `n-1` elements.

Comment: As a general rule, if existing code works differently after adding or changing other lines -- that is a good indication you have memory corruption somewhere, most likely due to abusing array bounds or an allocated block of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a[n-1];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];
}
```

You allocate less memory than you actually use. Period. This is an undefined behaviour, enjoy your nasal deamons. Everything can be observed since you enter the world of UB...

Alocate `n` integers, not `n-1`.

I wouldn't cricisize your attempt to reimplement bubble sort, that it is inefficient even comparing to canonic bubble sort implementations, the fact that if n is less than 3 you would get another UB... I guess this is out of scope of your question.